# Surjection from $On\times\mathbb{R}$ to $L(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: logic, set-theory

I'm trying to construct a surjeciton from $On\times\mathbb{R}$ to $L(\mathbb{R})$. (This apparently is the definable clousure of the transitive clousure of the reals, which I do not know if it differs from the definable clousure of the reals.)

The text I'm says to proceed by transfinite induction, but this is in part of a proof that is only supposed to use dependent choice and not the full axiom of choice.

My best bet is to fix a real $x$ and get a well-ordering of $L(x)$ based on the usual way of getting a well-ordering of $L$, which seems plausible but I'm unsure.

And anyway I'm also unsure that $L(\mathbb{R})$ is in fact equal $\cup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}L(x)$, which I would need to make the proposed proof work.

I also need this surjection to satisfy that for any $\alpha\in On$ its restriction to $\alpha\times\mathbb{R}$ is an element of $L(\mathbb{R})$.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: For the last part, what you really want is this surjection, let's call it $\pi$, to be definable (from a parameter in $L(\mathbb{R})$). It then follows, basically by comprehension, that $\pi \restriction \alpha \times \mathbb{R} \in L(\mathbb{R})$ for every $\alpha \in \operatorname{On}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, $L(\mathbb R)$ is not always equal to $\bigcup_{x\in\mathbb R}L(x)$.  For example, this union might not contain $\mathbb R$ as an element.

Now to get the surjection you want, notice first that, by definition of $L(\mathbb R)$, each of its elements is either in the transitive closure of $\mathbb R$ or in $L_{\alpha+1}(\mathbb R)$ for some $\alpha$ and therefore has the form 
$$
\{x\in L_\alpha(\mathbb R):(L_\alpha(\mathbb R),\in)\models\phi(x,p_1,\dots,p_k)\}
$$
for some formula $\phi$ and some parameters $p_i$ from earlier levels of the hierarchy. Such a description of $x$ can be coded by listing $\alpha$, the Gödel number of $\phi$, and similar descriptions of the $p_i$'s. All of this can be coded as finitely many ordinals and reals. (Note that, with a set-theorist's definition of $\mathbb R=\mathcal P(\omega)$, the elements of the transitive closure of $\mathbb R$ are reals and natural numbers.) Pairing functions let you code finitely many ordinals as a single ordinal, and finitely many reals as a single real. So every element of $L(\mathbb R)$ can be coded by an ordinal and a real; hence your surjection.

Comment: Also note that most authors define $L_{0}(\mathbb{R}) := V_{\omega +1} = \mathcal{P}(V_{\omega})$. This slightly complicates the construction of the desired surjection.

Comment: @StefanMesken Indeed, if you begin with $V_{\omega+1}$ instead of the transitive closure of $\mathcal P(\omega)$, then you need to change what I wrote (in parentheses) about the latter to "Note that the elements of $V_{\omega+1}$ can be coded by natural numbers (for the elements of $V_\omega$) and reals (for the new elements in $V_{\omega+1}$)."